# How to tag a redraw in all viewports?

Tags: scripting

I've designed a modal operator that changes the geometry of a mesh when the user clicks and drags the mouse.  I'm able to see the geometry update in the viewport I'm dragging in by tagging a redraw with

```
    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
```

However, this does not affect other viewports so I cannot see the updated geometry in any other viewport until I finish my operator and mouseover the other viewport.  Is there any way to tell Blender to updates those viewports right away?

Comment: may find a `Mesh.update()` has the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through all areas of the screen and tag them:

```
def modal(self, context, event):
    for area in context.screen.areas: 
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area.tag_redraw()
```